# how to query related three related tables using one query

Tags: mysql, join

I have three following tables.  The relationship is that each **report_param** and **report_frequency** is tied together using the intermediate table **report_freq_map**.  Is it possible to construct an SQL so that user can select all the report_param rows using the constraint like frequency='daily', instead of using frequency='1'.

Thanks,
-peter

```
mysql> describe report_params;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| test_level    | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sequence_name | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| step_name     | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descriptions  | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> describe report_frequency;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| frequency | varchar(25)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe report_freq_map;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| report_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| freq_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Two primary keys in one table?  Haven't seen that before.

Comment: @John at CashCommons: You are reading it wrong. It's not two primary keys, but one primary key consisting of two columns.

Comment: Ahh, OK.  Thanks Eton and Jasper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try joining the tables using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT report_params.*
FROM report_params
JOIN report_freq_map ON report_id = report_params.id
JOIN report_frequency ON freq_id = report_frequency.id
WHERE frequency = 'daily'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT report_params.id, test_level, sequence_name, step_name, descriptions
FROM report_params
JOIN report_freq_map
ON report_params.id = report_id
JOIN report_frequency
ON freq_id = report_frequency.id
WHERE frequency = 'daily'
```

(add DISTINCT after SELECT if you want to allow more than one frequncy, or you might have duplicate entries)